# Modelform Querysets with foreignKeys

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a challenge on how to best I can produce my form when adding products into my database. 
    model.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length...)


class Department(models.Model):
  categories = models.ForeignKey(Category)


class ProductDivisions(models.Model):
   departments = models.ForeignKey(Department)


class Product(models.Model):
division = models.ForeignKey(ProductDivisions)
title = models.CharField(max_length...)
```

and my FORMS.py

```
from .models import Category, Department, ProductDivisions

class ProductForm(forms.Form):

     category = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(),    empty_label=None, queryset=Category.objects.all

     department = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(), empty_label=None, queryset=Department.objects.all())
     productDivisions = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(), empty_label=None, queryset=ProductDivisions.objects.all())

     def __init__(self,categories_id,*args,**kwargs):
        super (ProductForm,self ).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['department'].queryset = Department.objects.all()
        self.fields['productdivisions'].queryset = ProductDivisions.objects.all()
```

So when I select the categories are doing fine but the departments' dropdown is showing all the departments including those from a different Category and the same happens to the ProductDivisions' dropdown, showing all of them together including the ones from a different department.

help me with a suggestion on how to make it proper so that I the Department dropdown only shows the ones from a specific category and also make the ProductDivisions dropdown to show the ones from a specific department, 
If the issue is with the DB, suggestions are welcome

**UPDATE: I also tried this** in the def  **init**() function, and there is completely nothing displayed on the Department and productdivisions dropdowns

```
 def __init__(self,categories_id,dept_id*args,**kwargs):
        super (ProductForm,self ).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['department'].queryset =      Department.objects.filter(id=categories_id)
        self.fields['productdivisions'].queryset = ProductDivisions.objects.filter(id=dept_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching all the departments.. you should do something like this.

```
def __init__(self,categories_id,*args,**kwargs):
        super (ProductForm,self ).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['department'].queryset = Department.objects.filter(categories=category_you_want_show)
```

Comment: Thanks man, I have equated the categories to True, and its giving options from only the first category, its a step forward though, but inquiring if I want it to be dynamic depending on the selected Category and not just the first one                                                                                    **self.fields['department'].queryset = Department.objects.filter(categories=True)**